# create date type in install profile

Tags: drush, datetime

I want the german date format in my install profile.

I tried in my setup script:

```
drush en l10n_update -y
drush vset site_default_country de
drush language-add de
drush language-default de
drush vset date_format_short "d.m.Y"
```

but it is not sufficient. It would not show up in the UI->configuration.regionalsettings as custom date format

manually I have to create a custom date format ("d.m.Y") first and then I can set is as wanted "date type",

I would do it via drush php-eval or better in profile-install function

**update:** clarified a bit

**update2** meanhile I discovered hook_date_format_types :-)  trying...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a custom date format, you should write this as a record in the database. In your `profile-install` function, you can use following code to accomplish this:

```
system_date_format_save(array(
    'format' => 'd.m.Y',
    'type' => 'custom',
    'locked' => 0,
    'is_new' => true,
));
```